# Keep cursor position when trying to edit phone number

Tags: reactjs

How can I keep the cursor position in the right spot? When I type out the phone number and it gets to the parenthesis in the phone number, it starts typing the number from there and leaves the cursor position behind which makes it type an incorrect number.

```
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { useStore } from '@shared/stores';

const PhoneInput = () => {
    const { phone } = useStore();

    const handlePhoneInput = (e) => {
        const formattedPhone = formatPhoneNumber(e.target.value);
        setPhone(formattedPhone); 
    }

    const formatPhoneNumber = (value) => {
        const newPhone = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
        const phoneLength = newPhone.length;
        if(phoneLength < 4) return newPhone;
        if(phoneLength < 7){
            return `(${newPhone.slice(0, 3)}) ${newPhone.slice(3)}`;
        }
        return `(${newPhone.slice(0, 3)}) ${newPhone.slice(3,6)}-${newPhone.slice(6,10)}`;
    } 
    
    return (
        <TextField
            label="Phone number"
            type="text"
            id="phone"
            onChange={handlePhoneInput}
            data-testid={'phone'}
            value={phone}
            textFieldProps={{
                inputMode: "numeric",
                pattern: "[0-9]*",
                maxLength: "14"
            }}
        />
    );
};

export default PhoneInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code below :

```
const handlePhoneInput = (e) => {
const input = e.target;
const startPosition = input.selectionStart;
const formattedPhone = formatPhoneNumber(input.value);
setPhoneState({...phoneState, [input.id]: formattedPhone}, () => {
// Restore the cursor position after the state has been updated
input.selectionStart = startPosition;
input.selectionEnd = startPosition;
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming up with a different solution to solve this.

```
    const handlePhoneInput = (e) => {
        const regex = /[0-9\-\(\)\s]/;
        if (e.target.value === '' || regex.test(e.target.value)) {
            const formattedPhone = formatPhoneNumber(e.target.value);
            setPhone(formattedPhone);
        }
    }

    const formatPhoneNumber = (phoneNumberString) => {
        var cleaned = ('' + phoneNumberString).replace(/\D/g, '');
        var match = cleaned.match(/^(1|)?(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/);
        if (match) {
            var intlCode = match[1] ? '+1 ' : '';
            return `${intlCode}(${match[2]}) ${match[3]}-${match[4]}`;
        }
        return phoneNumberString;
    }
```